# How do I modify the Bootstrap drop down navigation to work on iPad?

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

I am working on a Bootstrap site that has drop down navigation. The navigation works fine on the desktop version, but on iPad, if I have a live URL instead of a hashtag in the parent navigation, the drop down navigation does show and I am unable to access those links.

Here is the navigation I am working with:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div><!-- /.navbar-header -->

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="dropdown">
        <a href="/about-us/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="/about-us/history">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about-us/brochure">Brochure</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about-us/events">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about-us/testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about-us/botanical-gardens">Botanical Gardens</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="/the-collection/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">The Plants <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="/shrubs/">Shrubs</a></li>
    <li><a href="/groundcovers-grasses/">Groundcovers / Grasses</a></li>
    <li><a href="/trees/">Trees</a></li>
    <li><a href="/tropicals/">Tropicals</a></li>
    <li><a href="/bulbs/">Bulbs</a></li>
    <li><a href="/annuals/">Annuals</a></li>
    <li><a href="/perennials/">Perennials</a></li>
     <li><a href="/vines/">Vines</a></li>
    <li><a href="/container-gardens/">Container Gardens</a></li>
    <li><a href="/new-introductions/">New Introductions</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="/in-the-garden/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >In the Garden <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/plant-care/">Plant Care</a></li>
        <li><a href="/how-to/">How To</a></li>
        <li><a href="/style-advice/">Style Advice</a></li>
        <li><a href="/video/">Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="/expert-advice/">Expert Advice</a></li>
        <li><a href="/plant-spotlight/">Plant Spotlight</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>

<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Connect with Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Southern-Living-Plant-Collection/108615996233?fref=ts"><img src="/images/icon_facebook.png" alt="icon_facebook" width="21" height="21"> Like Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/@slplants"><img src="/images/icon_twitter.png" alt="icon_twitter" width="21" height="21"> Follow Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCumhUhgEt80YvG8p6mixmYA"><img src="/images/icon_youtube.png" alt="icon_youtube" width="21" height="21"> Watch Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact-us/request-newsletter"><img src="/images/icon_email.png" alt="icon_email" width="21" height="14"> Subscribe</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://instagram.com/southernlivingplantcollection"><img src="/images/icon_instagram.png" alt="icon_instagram" width="21" height="21"> #SLPlants</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about-us/events"><img src="/images/icon_cal.png" alt="icon_cal" width="21" height="22"> Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about-us/botanical-gardens"><img src="/images/icon_twitter.png" alt="icon_twitter" width="21" height="21"> Botanical Gardens</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</div>
```

I have also included this jQuery which is supposed to help with such issues, but I can only access the parent navigation.

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();

}, function() {
$(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();

});

$('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function(){
location.href = this.href;
});
});
```

I would appreciate some guidance on how to get both the parent navigation to function as well as the drop down links.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, the issue is on mobile devices you have to tap your dropdowns to get their items to show, but doing so takes you to the URL you've entered in the dropdown's href attribute instead, thus you can't actually click on the items in the dropdown because it's already navigating you to another page, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the following jQuery appears to solve the problem of the page navigating you away when clicking on a dropdown:

```
$('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function(){
        location.href = $(this).href;
    });
```

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/dLDQ2RNPNY)**